# Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Command `config` unrecognized

Tags: android, react-native

After Running Copied React-native project:

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Command `config` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

I did npm install but it didn't help.

Package.json

```
    {
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "node ./scripts/stfu.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^0.1.1",
    "@philly25/react-native-paytm": "^1.0.12",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^3.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.3.3",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.0.6",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.6",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
    "react-native-action-button": "file:./custom_modules/react-native-action-button",
    "react-native-android-sms-listener": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "file:./custom_modules/react-native-calendar-picker",
    "react-native-calendars": "file:./custom_modules/react-native-calendars",
    "react-native-carousel-view": "file:./custom_modules/react-native-carousel-view",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "file:./custom_modules/react-native-chart-kit",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-fetch-polyfill": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
    "react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-google-fit": "^0.9.17",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.11",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.3",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.1.3",
    "react-native-options-menu": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-otp-input": "file:./custom_modules/react-native-otp-input",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.7",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.0.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.13",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "react-native-select-input-ios": "file:./custom_modules/react-native-select-input-ios",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-slideable-calendar-strip": "file:./custom_modules/react-native-slideable-calendar-strip",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^11.0.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-tag-select": "file:./custom_modules/react-native-tag-select",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^8.0.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
    "realm": "^4.0.0-beta.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-jest": "25.1.0",
    "jest": "25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.12.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./app/res/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Sharing image:

Running npm install from the project folder PFA.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcYvz.png

Comment: What is this project? Can you share the package.json file? Did npm install execute correctly? What were you trying to run config for?

Comment: just check from which directory are you doing npm i ? does that directory has package.json inside it

Comment: @tomerpacific This is React-native Project. I am just Syncing the project from the android folder to load all dependencies.